# Date is saving one day less in DB - Mysql 8.0

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, amazon-rds

I am working in Spring-boot / JPA / (MySQL 8.0 in AWS RDS) Project. Date throughout application is saving one day less in Db. I connect AWS DB through Eclipse and before saving entity I checked and verified correct Date is received which is in UTC and my server time is also in UTC.

```
   @PostConstruct
    void started() {
       TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
     }
```

By above code I am restricting time receives in UTC. But It saves date one day prior.
DB Server and Application Server are both in Same Location so same timeZone.

Edit: About my further findings - Basically, I am using Angular App as front end. That is sending date in IST which is in my current Zone. Changes I made to make it work:

- mysql driver version to 5.1.47
- added useSSL=false in spring.datasource.url of application.properties
- Added below TimeZone in Application.java

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
```

Problem is: If User Accessing Application is from another timezone, its not working. By Keeping UTC as common, Somehow it is failing, When I restricted timezone to my current time zone in backend application then it worked.

This issue is related to TimeZone. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I think you should check your db server configurations. Maybe it takes the time of its location.

Comment: @akuma8 Yes, I am also thinking the same, that's why mentioned I am using AWS RDS MySQL 8.0. If anyone reading this knows about this, let us know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi @KuldeepChandel i hope you fixed this?
I am facing the exact same issue. same tech stack for the app.

Comment: Hi @DiliniPeiris, Try adding TimeZone in request date Object. It worked.